# Access control in Mysql

Tags: mysql, access-control

Does MySQL support the hierarchy of roles in the role Access Control ?

If the answer is positive, how is the connection between the role of the upper and lower levels?

Comment: No, it doesn't. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/access-control.html

Comment: Mysql v8.0 introduced roles in the mysql privilege system. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/roles.html  I do not understand the hierarchy and the connectuon between lower and upper levels parts of the question. Also, this question seems to be about database administration, not about programming, so should be migrated over to the dba sister site of SO.